# SQL database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I read about SQLite. I found information about making database in Android but I am wondering about opening existing database written somewhere else. Is there a possibility to open and read database from .sql file which I prepared earlier?

Comment: you can use http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use `SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToYourDatabase, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE));`

Otherwise you would probably need to open/read the .sql file and use it to create the database + data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);` is what you want .But only `.db` file works.

Comment: Thanks for this additional information about .db. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can open and read from the existing database file if your app has access to the `.DB` file. If the `.DB` file is in another app memory, you will not be able to access it. But if the `.DB` file is on external storage you can open and read from it.